# TextGrob R - fontface=bold but no bold

Tags: r, r-grid

I'm trying to create a header for my graph pages with the text being bold. The code I'm using is below, I set fontface=bold but this doesn't seem to be working. 
Is there somewhere else I need to set it as well?

```
t = textGrob(expression(underline("My Sample Header")),gp=gpar(fontfamily="serif",fontsize=16, fontface="bold",lineheight=1),vjust=.3,hjust=2.15)
```

Comment: You need `expression(bold(underline("My Sample Header")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one has answered this, you could do this two ways:

**Method 1:** Use expressions but do `expression(bold(underline(...)))` like:

```
t = textGrob(expression(bold(underline("My Sample Header"))),gp=gpar(fontfamily="serif",fontsize=16, fontface="bold",lineheight=1),vjust=.3,hjust=1)
grid.draw(t)
```

**Method 2:** Write a wrapper function which combines the `textGrob` with a line (probably a better option):

```
underlineText <- function(text, gpar, vjust, hjust){
  txt <- textGrob(text, gp=gpar, vjust = vjust, hjust = hjust)
  undLine <- segmentsGrob(x0 = txt$x - grobWidth(txt), y0 = txt$y - unit(0.55, "grobheight", txt), x1 = txt$x, y1 = txt$y - unit(0.55, "grobheight", txt))
  gt <- grobTree(txt, undLine)
}

grid.draw(underlineText("My Sample Header", gpar(fontfamily="serif",fontsize=16, fontface="bold",lineheight=1), vjust = 0.3, hjust = 1))
```